# Login 403. Hit with SA-CORE-2014-005

Tags: users

I don't know why, but I can't find a straight answer to this anywhere. I have a site that was by the vulnerability patched by SA-CORE-2014-005. I went into the database and deleted the user and applied the update via ftp, but I still can't log in. /user gives me a 403. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here is how I did it. Hopefully it will help someone else. After uploading the new drupal core, I went to the settings.php and set the $update_free_access = TRUE;. This will allow you to apply the update without being logged in by going to site.com/update.php.

Once that was done, in the database, I truncated the cache tables and I was able to log in and fix everything.

Hope this helps.